# How to handle HTTP Post Errors

Tags: perl, post

An error displays when I run my Perl script. It says, Internal Server Error. Error Code 500. How can I handle this?

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $url = "https://myhost/test/server.php";


my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $url);
$req->header('content-type' => 'application/json');


my $post_data = {"value": "sample", "value2":"sample2"};
$req->content($post_data);
#print $req->as_string;


my $resp = $ua->request($req);
if ($resp->is_success) {
    my $message = $resp->decoded_content;
    print "Received reply: $message\n";
}
 else {
    print "HTTP POST error code: ", $resp->code, "\n";
    print "HTTP POST error message: ", $resp->message, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid perl:

```
my $post_data = {"value": "sample", "value2":"sample2"};
```

You need to enclose your the value in single quotes:

```
my $post_data = '{"value": "sample", "value2":"sample2"}';
```

Alternatively, you can start with a perl hash, and build the json string using [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON):

```
use JSON;

my %hash = ( value => 'sample', value2 => 'sample2' );
my $post_data = to_json( \%hash );
```